# Link depois de fazer o upload de um arquivo

Tags: php, ajax

```
    <?php
$output_dir = "uploads/";


if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
    //Filter the file types , if you want.
    if ($_FILES["myfile"]["error"] > 0)
    {
      echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        //move the uploaded file to uploads folder;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);

     echo "Uploaded File :".$_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
    }

}
?>
```

Esse é meu codigo do upload, eu não estou conseguindo fazer que ele der o link depois de terminar o upload , tentei o codigo abaixo e não consegui o link... Ainda estou aprendendo php por isso gostaria de saber o que está errado exatamente...

```
echo "<a src='$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];".$_FILES["myfile"]["name"].>" Link "<a />";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $output_dir = "uploads/";


    if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
    {
        //Filter the file types , if you want.
        if ($_FILES["myfile"]["error"] > 0)
        {
          echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            //move the uploaded file to uploads folder;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
         $arquivo = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/".$_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
         echo "Uploaded File :".$_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
         echo "<a href='$arquivo'>Arquivo</a>";
        }

    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Durante o processo de upload o ficheiro vai primeiro receber um caminho temporário `$_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"]` e depois `$_FILES["myfile"]["name"]`. O segundo é o destino final que pode ser acedido do lado do cliente.

O segundo argumento de `move_uploaded_file()` precisa exatamente desse caminhi/path, e podes usá-lo. Sugiro também passares isso num JSON assim podes estilizar no lado do JS mais facilmente.

```
$destino = $output_dir.$_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"], $destino);
echo "Uploaded File :".$destino;
// ou, em JSON: echo '{"path":"'.$destino.'", "message":"Uploaded File"}';
```